# Android O Emulator crashes and closes itself after I run Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, crash, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo

I'm on Linux (Debian x64) and I decided to test new Android O emulator from Google. Basically, it works fine. But whenever I try to run Chrome browser, emulator crashes and closes itself immediately without any error message. Emulator is Android O x86, with Google Services.

Can anybody confirm that and, maybe does anybody know any workaround? My app uses Chrome as backend for Facebook login, so I am unable to debug it.

[edit]
So I tried to run emulator from command line and I see it throws segmentation fault error.

Comment: Have you installed the graphic card driver in your host system?

Comment: Yes of course. Also it's only on Android 8 emulator. Older Android version work just fine

Comment: Have you analyzed the logs of the android device monitor yet?